# How do you compare different datasets' performance in an unbiased way?

Tags: cross-validation, random-forest

I am working with a Random Forest implementation and wanted to try out some parameter tweaking as well as some different dataset configurations. Basically my datasets look like this:

- I have a set **A** and **B**, which have different data from different sources.
- Then I have set **C** which has *some* samples from A and *some* from B but *not* all.
- Then I have a set **D** which has all samples from A and B combined.

And what I want to compare is the performance of the classifier when trained with:

- Set **A** and **X** trees, Set **A** and **Y** trees, Set **A** and **Z** trees,
- Set **B** and **X** trees, Set **B** and **Y** trees, Set **B** and **Z** trees,
- etc...

Where X, Y, Z equal some number of trees that I determine.

Now what I had **originally** planned to do was separate a test set and then use cross-validation to compare the performance of the different tree count configurations and apply the best to the test set at the end. However, with these different datasets I am confused about how to accomplish this. If I do cross-validation on each dataset then I am only comparing the relative performance among the tree configurations for that particular dataset and **not** comparing the performance of the different datasets.

One thought I have is to have 2 test sets, one that I use at the very end to get a more realistic estimate of my chosen training configuration's performance. And then another that I used as a sort of second validation set, wherein I basically take each cross-validation training set, and validate them on both the relevant k fold AND a similarly sized validation set that contains values from ALL datasets.

So to outline this a little clearer here is an example,

1. I partition dataset **A** for k-fold cross validation.
2. I train on the first k-1 partitions in the cross validation cycle.
3. I validate on the validation partition for that cross validation cycle.
4. Then, I validate the classifier on a separate but similarly sized validation set that encompasses samples from **D** (i.e. A + B).
5. Repeat steps 1-4 which each of the k partitions as is described in cross validation process.
6. Repeat steps 1-5 with datasets **B** and **C**.
7. Determine the optimum training configuration and try that and only that one on the final test set which was separated from **D** at the start and which has samples not included in any of the training or validation sets.

Basically I'm looking for an answer to tell me either:

- Yes, that is a sensible approach.
- Or no, that is not a sensible approach and demonstrates a lack of understanding and **here's why: ____**.

Greatly appreciate any responses!